# Python writing txt to csv in columns

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the data from the .txt file to the csv. I am first reading the data from the .txt files and only those which are tagged with specific strings. I am then modifying these data by removing the tag strings.

```
import substring
import codecs
import threading
import csv


global y
with open('output.txt', "r",encoding="utf-8") as input:
        y = 0
        for line in input:
            if line.startswith('Warmateba:'):
                    y=y+1


class TimeThread(threading.Thread):
        def run(self):

            with open('output.txt', "r",encoding="utf-8") as input:
                    for line in input:
                        if line.startswith('Warmateba:'):
                                s = (next(input))
                                p = s[5:len(s)]
                                print(p)
                                with open('userInfo.csv', 'w') as time:
                                    for i in range(0,y)
                                            writer = csv.writer(time, delimiter=' ')
                                            writer.writerow(p)

time_thread=TimeThread()
time_thread.start()
time_thread.join()
```

This is the code I am using, at first I am trying to count how many inputs I have and assign it to y. In the original text file each input has a specific local time to it thus in the TimeThread I am trying to convert this local time from .txt to csv and put them in columns. The p=s[5:len(s)] just modifies the string by removing the tag string and just leaving the time like '2020-06-14 13:24:04'.

In my test txt file I have just two time inputs and whenever I run this code the only the last input gets written to the .csv file in [1,A1], could anybody help me on how to fix this code and write both inputs to the .csv without overwriting?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is your code indented correctly? And output.txt: you've opened it for reading in two places. Perhaps you should read it in just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
with open('userInfo.csv', 'w') as time
With
with open('userInfo.csv', 'a+') as time
```

Since you were using w as Write mode the file was replaced everytime and only last value persisted

Comment: Yes of course I fixed it, how stupid of me thanks a lot. I also removed for loop as it was unnecessary.